# php compile build title

Tags: build, compilation, php

I have googled many times using various key phrases to know how can I set phpinfo() build title. Attached image can be explain better[image: ![phpinfo build title]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQsdJ.jpg)

I have changed `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` `Loaded Configuration File` `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` but couldn't change the **top title**.

Any suggestion/help?

Thanks for reading..

Comment: did you restarted the apache  service after changes made ?

Comment: I have compiled PHP in another server with port 808, but phpinfo title was "php version -x.y.z"